Getting ppg on WearOS smartwatches and interpreting Samsung HR Raw Sensor data
I am developing an app for WearOS (API target 30) smartwatches that should include a collector of users' ppg. However, I am having problems trying to find a way to implement it.
I am using a Galaxy Watch 4 for testing.
I have read other questions on this topic (in particular this ), but I am unable to retrieve the ppg data, probably because Samsung blocks access to it (and it is not possible to apply for Samsung Privileged Health SDK ). However, using Samsung HR Raw Sensor I get an array of 16 values, 7 of which are constants and I am unable to interpret them. I have found no documentation online.
Does anyone have any idea of a general approach to getting ppg data from Android smartwatches, especially on Samsung devices?
I tried to check Health Connect API, Health Service API and Health Platform API documentations but without success.
